# Azure Function unable to read app settings and connection strings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I created an HTTP Trigger function in Azure with the hope of reading data from an Azure SQL database. I configured the connection string in the Connection Strings section of the Function App as shown in the image below

[image: Connection String Error]

I used the below code to try and read the connection string.

```
var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TempleDataContext"].ConnectionString;
```

On execution i see the below error in the logs.

> 2018-10-24T18:13:56.385 [Information] Script for function 'donors1'
>   changed. Reloading. 2018-10-24T18:13:56.601 [Information] Compilation
>   succeeded. 2018-10-24T18:13:58.511 [Information] Executing
>   'Functions.donors1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called
>   via the host APIs.', Id=8b140087-4b50-450e-829c-f7abd9e3a1eb)
>   2018-10-24T18:13:59.067 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function
>   processed a request. 2018-10-24T18:13:59.245 [Error] Executed
>   'Functions.donors1' (Failed, Id=8b140087-4b50-450e-829c-f7abd9e3a1eb)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I wanted to test what all were coming back on the ConnectionStrings object and changed the code to

```
var cnnStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
    foreach(var c in cnnStrings)
    {
        log.LogInformation(c.ToString());
    }
```

When I check the logs, this is the info I see.

> 2018-10-24T18:16:53.755 [Information] Script for function 'donors1'
>   changed. Reloading. 2018-10-24T18:16:54.540 [Information] Compilation
>   succeeded. 2018-10-24T18:16:55.917 [Information] Executing
>   'Functions.donors1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called
>   via the host APIs.', Id=508c49bf-d5e6-4a99-b1db-e1a79545fa91)
>   2018-10-24T18:16:56.063 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function
>   processed a request. 2018-10-24T18:16:56.070 [Information] data
>   source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User
>   Instance=true 2018-10-24T18:16:56.079 [Information] Executed
>   'Functions.donors1' (Succeeded,
>   Id=508c49bf-d5e6-4a99-b1db-e1a79545fa91)

I am confused as to where it is getting the ConnectionString information.

Just to test a thoery I also added a few lines to read app settings

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
foreach(var a in appSettings)
{
    log.LogInformation(a.ToString());
}
```

It did not show me any information for these lines.

I am writing the Azure Functions directly in the portal using C# Script. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In function v2, you should use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("string_name",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)` to get values from Application settings and connection strings.

Note for the connection strings:

when use the above method, the first parameter depends on the Type. It means that when the type of the connection string is `SQLAZURE`, then the first parameter should be SQLAZURE + "CONNSTR" + "_stringName". The screenshot is as below:
[image]

The code sample as below:

```
    //for connection string
    string connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_sqldb_connection",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    log.LogInformation("the connection string is: " + connStr);

    //for app settings
    string appStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    log.LogInformation("the string in app settings is: " + appStr);
```

The test result as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ivan. That helped. Is there any documentation from Microsoft that tells us about this change?

Comment: Seams that there is no official document about this. If I get anything about this, will let you know.

Comment: It seems that ConnectionStrings are handled differently when running the v2 Function locally and using local.settings.json, than they are when the function is running in Azure. See https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/717

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have wasted my last 48 hours to figure out why System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key") is not working in production. But It works now! (just need to add "SQLAZURECONNSTR_" in prefix). Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing.  Unless you are using Entity Framework (as the image says), the connection string does not get attached.  I just put my connection string in the appsettings and moved on.

Comment: Yup, just putting connection strings in the Application Settings in Azure, and the Values section of the local.settings.json, is easy and works. Then just use ` string connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`